# lost interactive console in pyDev 2.6.0

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I'm running eclipse 3.5.2 on Mac OS X 10.5.8.
I just allowed eclipse to update me to PyDev 2.6.0, and suddenly I can't start a PyDev console.  I'm using the same procedure that previously worked (from the "Console" pulldown, I select "PyDev Console" and then select the "Python console" button), but nothing happens.  I haven't changed any settings elsewhere in eclipse.
Anybody know why this might be happening?  Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something in your error log? It's possible that PyDev is using some API that's not available in Eclipse 3.5 (it's definitely not tested as much on that version as in the latest Eclipse versions).

Comment: Fabio, Thanks for the suggestion, I'd forgotten about the log.  There was an error.  I've installed eclipse 4.2 and pydev 2.6, and everything works now.  (the universal fixes: reboot the hardware, upgrade the software...).